# PHP how right use explode?

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I get string:

```
$res = "RESULT: SUCCESS
NUMBER_TYPE:    0";
```

I want get "RESULT" and for this i use `explode`:

```
$arr = explode('\n\r', $res);
$result = trim(explode('RESULT:', $arr[0]));
```

But i get `Arrayfalse`

Tell me please how correctly get `RESULT`?

P.S.: result should been `SUCCESS`

Comment: `if (preg_match('/RESULT:\s*(\w+)/', $res, $match)) echo $match[1];` - http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: @deceze thanks but need with `explode`

Comment: Just saying that sometimes there are better tools... :)

Comment: Any reason why you need explode? It really is not the right method for this parsing job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [explode](http://www.php.net/explode) then [preg_split](http://www.php.net/preg_split)

```
$arr = explode(':', $res);
$arr = preg_split('/\s+/', $arr[1]);
echo $arr[1];
```

You can also use this one with explode only.

```
$arr = explode("\n", $res);
$arr= explode(":", $arr[0]);
echo trim($arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$ex = explode(":",$res);
$result = explode("\n",$ex[1]);
$result = $result[0];
echo trim($result); //echoes SUCCESS
```

Or :

```
$ex = explode("\n", $res);
$result = explode(":", $ex[0]);
$result = $result[1];
echo trim($result); //echoes SUCCESS
```

**[Demo 1](http://codepad.org/kFgLtovz)**

**[Demo 2](http://codepad.org/hi7aIbyD)**

Comment: It will show `SUCCESS NUMBER_TYPE` not `SUCCESS` ...which the OP doesnt want.

Comment: `'\n'` is "\n", not a line break.

Comment: @deceze I didn't understood you

Comment: @AlirezaFallah, Did you try the code yourself before posting this as answer ?

Comment: @AlirezaFallah in result with your answer will be `  SUCCESS
NUMBER_TYPE` with line break after `SUCCESS`. try you code please.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran , did YOU tried it? I tried and it echoes **SUCCESS**

Comment: @AlirezaFallah i try in my code and get `SUCCESS NUMBER_TYPE` with line break after `SUCCESS`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran  look at demo

Comment: @AlirezaFallah row when you print is not row which get from script. but big thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Trying Doing this

```
$arr = explode(':', $res);
$result = explode(' ', $arr[1]);
print_r($result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first comment to your answer is the solution. But - for any reason - if you want to get all the keys and values, you can use preg_match for each line. A quick example:

```
<?php

$res = "RESULT: SUCCESS
NUMBER_TYPE:    0";

$arr = explode("\n", $res);

foreach($arr as $line)
{
    if(preg_match('/^([A-Z_]+):\s+?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$/', $line, $matches))
    {
        echo "Key: " . $matches[1] . " - Value: " . $matches[2] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Key: RESULT - Value: SUCCESS
Key: NUMBER_TYPE - Value: 0
```